# Add values to pivot table laravel

Tags: php, laravel, pivot

When I want to save a reaction to a ticket I've three tables (in laravel):

```
-Tickets
-Reaction
-Reaction_Tickets (pivot table)
```

When I want to save a reaction I do it like this:

```
public function addReaction(Request $request, $slug)
    {
        $ticket = Ticket::whereSlug($slug)->firstOrFail();
        $reaction = new reactions(array(
            'user_id' => Auth::user()->id,
            'content' => $request->get('content')
            ));

        return redirect('/ticket/'.$slug)->with('Reactie is toegevoegd.');
    }
```

But now of course it's not added to the pivot table. And I can't add it because I don't have a model of it. What's the right way of doing this?

EDIT:

```
-Tickets

public function reactions()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\reactions');
}

-Reactions

public function tickets()
{
    return $this->hasOne('App\tickets');
}
```

Comment: Can you provide your relationship definitions for those three models?

Comment: I've demonstrated this in my answer, but be aware that the inverse of `belongsToMany` on a many-to-many relationship is also `belongsToMany`, as many `Tickets` can have many `Reactions`.

Comment: Oke, but a reaction can only have one ticket right? A reaction doesn't belong to many tickets I would say.

Comment: Sorry, missed this comment. Yes and no. If you're using a pivot table, then it's assumed you're using a many-to-many relationship. If you were using a `hasOne`, then each `Reaction` would have a foreign key `ticket_id`, which would link directly to the `Ticket` it belongs to, and you wouldn't need the pivot table at all.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the Laravel documentation, you need to save and attach the `Reaction` to the `Ticket`:

```
$reaction = new reactions(array(
    'user_id' => Auth::user()->id,
    'content' => $request->get('content')
));
$reaction->save(); // Now has an ID
$tickets->reactions()->attach($reaction->id);
```

In your `Ticket` model, you need to have the relationship defined:

```
class Ticket extends Model {
    protected $table = "tickets";

    public function reactions(){
        return $this->belongsToMany("App\Reaction"); 
    }
}
```

And you should have the inverse defined on `Reaction`:

```
class Reaction extends Model {
    protected $table = "reactions";

    public function tickets(){
        return $this->belongsToMany("App\Ticket"); 
    }
}
```

If your models are set-up like so, you shouldn't have any issue attaching the new `Reaction` to your existing `Ticket` via your pivot table.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but why do I only have to attach a reaction id and not a userId?

Comment: Why would a `Reaction`'s user_id matter to the ticket? I assume your pivot table has the following structure: `ticket_id, reaction_id`. So `attach`ing them would insert an entry for those columns in your pivot table.

Comment: Yes sorry I mean ticket_id -_-

Comment: Ah, no worries. Then the reason you only have to pass the `Reaction`'s id is that the `->attach()` function is called from the `Ticket`, meaning the ticket_id is already known to the insert statement. It would be reversed if you attached a `Reaction` to a `Ticket`: `$reaction->tickets()->attach($ticket->id)`; Notice you'd only need the ticket_id.